# C# WPF: Listbox with drag to select text

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, listbox

I need to create a WPF ListBox that supports two features:

**Content Converter Binding:**
The items in the ListBox need to be passed to a converter that converts the items to a text format.

**Display items in a way that lets users select and copy text from ListBox items**
I need the text of each ListBox item to be selectable. Users want to use their mouse to drag-to-select parts of the elements so they can copy the text to their clipboard.

I implemented [this copy/paste solution][1] but it does not let a user select parts of the ListBox item text, rather it supports copying the entire text.

I'm able to create a ListBox using the converter, but I can not figure out how to put the converted text into a control that lets users select the displayed text. Here is what I have:

```
<ListBox Name="FinishedTestErrorsListBox"
         FontSize="12"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedComparisonResult.TestFailItems}">

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource testFailItemConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I've tried adding a TextBox to the DataTemplate as shown below...

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource testFailItemConverter}}"/>
```

... but this creates a runtime error caused by sending the wrong type of object to the converter. I know here I'm not setting up the converter binding properly, though I don't have a good grasp on how I should setup the binding here or why this causes errors.

So, my question is:

**What content container can I use to let users select text from the individual ListBox items?**

Thank you for any help,
Charlie

**EDIT**

Here's the converter code...

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
     ITestFailItem i = (ITestFailItem)value;
     return i.Itemize();
}
```

**EDIT 2**

The following runtime error is throw when the ListBox is first initialized:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll 

Additional information: Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception
```

**EDIT 3**

The culprit is a line of code I'd omitted from the original snippet as I thought it was irrelevant - I've learned a good lesson along the way!

**Extension Question**

Why does the following snippet cause an error? How can I achieve the desired affect of making the textbox span the entire containing grid?

```
<TextBox Width="*"
         Text="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource testFailItemConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: What other requirements does the ListBox have (selection, right click, etc.)? Can you show us your Converter code? Why not modify the Converter, or make a new one, to support the TextBlock?

Comment: Added the Converter code in an edit. I'm not sure how I would modify it to support the TextBlock. There are no other requirements for the ListBox.

Comment: What's that runtime error you're getting? Whatever `Itemize` returns, the TextBlock should be able to show it as text (it uses `ToString` by default). Anyway, TextBlocks don't support text selection either, so this won't help you... Have you tried using a `TextBox` with `IsReadOnly="True"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have You tried TextBox? You can select text inside textbox. Path have to be changed to `Path=.`

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource testFailItemConverter}}" />
```

There is not much code to work with, but this code works for me:

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflowTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:s="clr-namespace:StackOverflowTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <s:TestFailItemConverter x:Key="testFailItemConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Name="FinishedTestErrorsListBox"
         FontSize="12"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedComparisonResult.TestFailItems}">

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!--<ContentControl Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource testFailItemConverter}}"/>-->
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource testFailItemConverter}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Model's code:

```
public class Dummy
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> TestFailItems { get; set; }

        public Dummy()
        {
            TestFailItems = new ObservableCollection<string>(new List<string> { "a", "b" });
        }
    }
    public class Model
    {
        public Dummy SelectedComparisonResult { get; set; }

        public Model()
        {
            SelectedComparisonResult = new Dummy();
        }
    }
```

Converter's code:

```
public class TestFailItemConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return "aa";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok the problem was with code that I'd decided to omit from this question because I thought it was irrelevant - go figure. In the TextBox, I have the tag " Width="*" ". Any idea why this causes the problem? I'm trying to get the textbox to span the width of it's containing grid?

Comment: I can't see the containing Grid's code, but most likely it's not the TextBox You should change, but make the Grid's column wider.

Comment: `Width="*"` will only work in a few cases, like Grids or DataGrids rows and columns definitions. For a `TextBox` to use the whole width of its container, you should use `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` (and set no `Width`, of course).

Answer (score 3):

Try this. TextBlocks don't support text selection, but TextBoxes do. You just have to make it read-only so the user can't modify the text, and change its border thickness and background so they look like labels:

```
<ListBox Name="FinishedTestErrorsListBox"
         FontSize="12"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedComparisonResult.TestFailItems}">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <converter:TestFailItemConverter x:Key="testFailItemConverter" />
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=.,
                                    Converter={StaticResource testFailItemConverter},
                                    Mode=OneWay}"
                     BorderThickness="0"
                     Background="Transparent"
                     IsReadOnly="True"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: With your implementation, I continue to get this runtime error:

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Comment: Additional information: Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.

Comment: Weird... That sounds like your Converter is not defined in your Resources, or something like that. Have you added it? Did it work with the ContentControl?

Comment: I've added the Converter to the ListBox Resources in my example. Replace `converter` with whichever namespace you define for it.

Comment: The problem is solved - it had to do with code I omitted from the snippet. I apologize for the mistake - I was hoping to make the code simpler to understand and by doing so missed the error. Thank you for you help